# Avoiding ACF get_field and returning to core Wordpress function

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-query, core

```
function slb_subscriber_column_data( $column, $post_id ) {  
  // setup our return text
  $output = '';  
  switch( $column ) {    
    case 'title':
      // get the custom name data
      $fname = get_field('slb_first_name', $post_id );
      $lname = get_field('slb_last_name', $post_id );
      $output .= $fname .' '. $lname;
      break;
    case 'email':
      // get the custom email data
      $email = get_field('slb_email', $post_id );
      $output .= $email;
      break;    
  }  
  // echo the output
  echo $output;  
}

function slb_register_custom_admin_titles() {
    add_filter(
        'the_title',
        'slb_custom_admin_titles',
        99,
        2
    );
}

function slb_custom_admin_titles( $title, $post_id ) {
   
    global $post;  
    $output = $title;   
    if( isset($post->post_type) ):
      switch( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'slb_subscriber':
        $fname = get_field('slb_first_name', $post_id );
        $lname = get_field('slb_last_name', $post_id );
        $output = $fname .' '. $lname;
        break;
      }
      endif;   
    return $output;
}
```

The above is the code from a plugin. I was going through a course on udemy.com.
The author is not responsive.

Issue:
Although the whole approach was to create a setting without any third party, the author seems to have made the code dependent on the ACF plugin somehow. as soon as I disable the ACF plugin the screen goes blank:

[image]

I feel that the culprit is this part: `get_field` How can I get rid of this. what in general may be used from WordPress functions to extract this information without this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default WP function `get_post_meta` to get meta from the post, here is the link to the  official documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

For example `get_field('slb_first_name', $post_id )` must be replaced with `get_post_meta($post_id, 'slb_first_name', true)`

Comment: Thanks before posting I tried that(=`'get_post_meta`) looks like there is something more to this underneath than what appears at the periphery.

Comment: `$post_id` can be called directly or we need to store that in a certain variable?

Comment: Appreciate your help, finally, it worked.